# tmux -- naming windows and selecting them via fuzzy matching

Tags: vim, tmux

I want to be able to name my tmux windows and select them using fuzzy matching (similar to LustyJuggler or Ctrl-P in vim).

Is this possible with tmux?

Answer (score 4):

Default tmux has almost exactly what you want:

<kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> Rename current window

<kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> (single quote) Prompt for window index to select

Note this 'window index' wording is a little misleading. This prompt actually accepts `target-window` which is quite powerful and includes:

> 5. The start of a window name, such as `mysession:mywin'.
> 6. As an fnmatch(3) pattern matched against the window name.

Not quite fuzzy matching but pretty close to it. So if you have your named windows

- foo
- bar
- buz

you can jump between them very quickly:

- <kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>ba</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>C-b</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>bu</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Nice! is there a way to make this case insensitive ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are links to scripts that use [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to fuzzy search and select a `pane`:

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples-(tmux)#select-pane

https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples#tmux

I guess it won't be too hard to adjust those for fuzzy searching `windows`.

EDIT:

Change this line:

`panes=$(tmux list-panes -s -F '#I:#P - #{pane_current_path} #{pane_current_command}')`

To:

`panes=$(tmux list-panes -s -F '#I:#P #W - #{pane_current_path} #{pane_current_command}')`

(I added the `#W` which also prints the `window` name)

Answer (score 1):

Tmux can't do that by default.

Google doesn't return many results and this question is number two or three depending on the query but [these zsh scripts](https://github.com/tarruda/dot-files/tree/master/.zsh/tmux.d) might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's necessary.

You can see the index of every window at the status line, then a PREFIX+number will bring you anywhere you want, much quicker than any search.

If you have so much windows to need a search, maybe they are too much.

Comment: I think you can not easily judge what's necessary for the OP... For example, I do not use multiple tmux windows, but separate terminal windows - about 20, often - on 16 virtual screens. My firefox has about 100 tabs open normally - do you think that's too much? I don't (Ok, sometimes...).

Answer (score 0):

You can name windows in tmux with the default keybinding <kbd>prefix</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or by executing:

```sh
tmux rename-window "<the-name>"
```

I made a shell function to fuzzy find a tmux window by name (using [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)) and then switching to it:

```sh
tmux_fzf_window() {
    window_list=$(tmux list-windows -F '#{window_index} #{window_name}')
    window_index=$(echo "$window_list" | fzf | awk '{ print $1 }')
    tmux select-window -t $window_index
}
```

And I use it in my `tmux.conf` like this:

```
bind-key f run "tmux split-window -l 12 'bash -ci tmux_fzf_window'"
```

Then when you press <kbd>prefix</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, a tmux pane appears at the bottom with a list of windows, that you can fuzzy filter and select to switch to that window.

Note: this overrides the default <kbd>prefix</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> keybinding which is set to "Find window", which works somewhat similar but less fuzzy and interactive.

Inspired by https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/Examples#tmux